# Getting Japanese characters from a C# list box

Tags: c#, winforms

I've populated a listbox (Visual Studio 2010, C#, Windows form) with Japanese characters. This works fine and I can see the Japanese characters in the list box. The problem is getting them out of it.

When I've dealt with list boxes before, if I wanted to retrieve a the item that is currently selected, I use this code (obviously the name of the list box changes):

```
string strSelectedHiragana = lbHiraganaList.Items[lbHiraganaList.SelectedIndex] as string;
```

If I populate the list box with Western characters ('a', 'b', 'c' and 'd') to test, this works fine and I can retrieve those characters from the list box.

If, however, I populate the list box with Japanese hiragana characters, the string strSelectedHiragana is null. If I mouse over the lbHiraganaList during a program break, it tells me the SeletedItem is the character I want. Yet, the line after, that string is null.

The function simply takes the character from this list box and adds it to a string. This all works fine when dealing with Western characters.

I hope someone can offer help on how to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Okay, so I needed a little more detail and I have done this with a series of five images.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikg8F.jpg) - this shows the code used to populate the list box with hiragana characters as well as the result.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1mWX.jpg) - this shows a test with me populating the same list box with the Western characters 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd', as well as the result.

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlkbJ.jpg) - this shows the button on the form that's used and the code that it calls when clicked. This image also shows which text box the code is referring to.

[Image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98jVG.jpg) - this shows what happens when I put a break point in the program during the button click event for that button. It shows the state of the variables and we can see that the selected letter is 'c'. Below this we can see the outcome, which is the letter 'c' appearing in the text box.

[Image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGhJ8.jpg) - this is the same scenario as image 4, except this time I'm using the hiragana populated box instead of the Western characters. As you can see, there are various nulls there and the text box is not added to. There is a mouse over for 'SelectedIndex', and that shows up as '5'. In fact, I'll just include a watch on lbHiraganaList as another image: [Image 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr9UJ.jpg)

Comment: `lbHiraganaList.Text` - does that show the correct string?

Comment: Yes, that shows the data I am expecting. But when I attempt to get the item out of the listbox, the string I give it to is null. If it were gibberish that needed the right encoding I could understand, but I can't do much with null. Also I updated my post to include images to help.